# How to count no. of child for a parent in a hierarchical SQL -SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have one table in the below structure. I want to get all the Unit details with count of Child Units, here in the below example Child count of Unit ID -6 is 2 and Unit ID 5 is 0 (SINCE NULL) in **SQL SERVER 2008**

```
UnitID | Name   | ParentUnitId
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1      | Unit A | NULL
2      | Unit B | 1
3      | Unit C | NULL
4      | Unit D | 1
5      | Unit E | NULL
6      | Unit F | 3
7      | Unit G | 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to get a count of the number of records that have a value for `ParentUnitId' and then left join from you main table to that subquery. Something like this...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp;

SELECT
    *
INTO #Temp
FROM 
( VALUES
     ( 1, 'Unit A', NULL), 
     ( 2, 'Unit B', 1),
     ( 3, 'Unit C', NULL),
     ( 4, 'Unit D', 1),
     ( 5, 'Unit E', NULL),
     ( 6, 'Unit F', 3),
     ( 7, 'Unit G', 3)
) AS t ([UnitID], [Name], [ParentUnitID])

SELECT a.*, COALESCE(b.ChildCount, 0) AS 'ChildCount' FROM #Temp a
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT ParentUnitID, COUNT(*) AS 'ChildCount' FROM #Temp
WHERE ParentUnitID IS NOT null
GROUP BY ParentUnitID
) b ON a.UnitID = b.ParentUnitID
```

Noel

Comment: Is there any other way instead of hard-coding values in query, I have 1000 no. of records.

Comment: I was inserting into #Temp merely as an example. You would use the second query only substituting whatever you table is for #Temp.